# Hierarchy search on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hierarchical-data

I have a CouchDB with below documents:

```
{"key": 1001, "site": "base", "name": "A"}
{"key": 1002, "site": "base", "name": "B"}
{"key": 1001, "site": "site-1", "name": "B"}
{"key": 1002, "site": "site-1-1", "name": "A"}
```

For site, it will be a hierarchical structure like below:

```
base
|---site-1
|---|---site-1-1
```

"site-1-1" inherits from "site-1", and "site-1" inherits from "base".

**Question: Is there any way to get the below data by ElasticSearch:**

base:  1001 - A, 1002 - B

site-1: 1001 - B, 1002 - B

site-1-1: 1001 - B, 1002 - A

Comment: As mentioned by @vladislav-kysliy your option here is the `parent-child` relationship, may you need some help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parent-child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) relationship